# Unhappiness Jumps

Tags: civilization-5-brave-new-world

In the new Civilization 5 Brave New World expansion I had the unhappiness level jump from 2 to 32 in one turn, and then to 44 the next turn for no discernible reason. Roughly a third of my cities were puppets. I replayed this scenario a half dozen ways and no matter what I did the unhappiness level jumped the same amount within the same short period of time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds very much like someone with a lot of tourism influence over you just became part of an [ideology](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Ideology_%28Civ5%29) different to your own. Or the world ideology was voted on, and it's different to yours.

If you can provide more information about the situation, I can give you more suggestions as to the cause.

Comment: I'll check out the ideology issue and repost. Thanks.

Comment: @Skribbler did you ever work this one out?